# Scroll to top function not working (showing as undefined)

Tags: javascript, dom

A colleague of mine created the following function:

```
function scrolltotop() { scroll(document.body,document.body.scrollTop,0,500,0); }
```

Here is the scroll code:

```
 function scroll(ele,from,to,duration,time) {
   if (from<=0) from=0;
   if (to<=0) to=0;
   if (time>=duration) return;
   var delta=(to-from);
   var progress=time/duration*Math.PI/2;
   var pos=delta*Math.sin(progress);
   setTimeout(function() { ele.scrollTop=from+pos; 
    scroll(ele,from,to,duration,time+10) },10
   );
}
```

It used ti work well, however it no longer works. When i go to the console and type:

`scrolltotop (no parenthesis)` it returns the function declaration.

Now if I try to execute the function using parenthesis it says `undefined`.

What's going on here? It used to work fine?

**NOTE:** My javascript file is located at the bottom of the page however this function only gets called after this loading of the bottom file.

Answer (score 1):

Your colleague's function is fine, tho I'd suggest he utilizes `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout`.

The reason why there is no scrolling going on is because of `document.body`. On some browsers (eg.Safari), the document's scroll is applied to the body element. So your code probably works for Safari. However on Chrome and Firefox the scroll is applied to the html element.

I think using `document.documentElement` works for all borwsers. Please do let me know if it works.

```js
function scrolltotop() { scroll(document.documentElement,document.documentElement.scrollTop,0,500,0); 
}

 function scroll(ele,from,to,duration,time) {
   if (from<=0) from=0;
   if (to<=0) to=0;
   if (time>=duration) return;
   var delta=(to-from);
   var progress=time/duration*Math.PI/2;
   var pos=delta*Math.sin(progress);
   requestFrame(function() { ele.scrollTop=from+pos; 
    scroll(ele,from,to,duration,time+10) });
}


var requestFrame = function() { // requestAnimationFrame cross browser
  return (
   window.requestAnimationFrame ||
   window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
   window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
   window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
   window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
   function(func) {
    window.setTimeout(func, 1000 / 50);
   }
  );
 }()
```

```css
body{
  font-size: 32pt;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
<br>
<input type="button" value="Go to Top" onclick="scrolltotop()">
```

Oh, and about that `undefined`: that's just the return value of the called function, which is in your case `undefined` because you're not returning anything.